# Tableau LOD to find median

Tags: filter, tableau-api, level-of-detail

I have some data:

```
Inst    Dest_Group  Dest Cipn1  N
I1  C   a   43
I1  F   a   63
I1  U   a   54
I1  C   b   96
I1  F   b   3
I1  U   b   78
I1  C   c   12
I1  F   c   65
I1  U   c   49
I2  C   a   3
I2  F   a   47
etc...
```

My worksheet is set up so that `[Dest Cipn1]` is a row, and `[Dest Group]` is a column. They display `[value]` as a bar chart. `[value] = {include [Inst] : sum([N])} / {fixed [Inst] : sum([N])}`

This worksheet is filtered on `[Inst] = I1`. I would like to add a reference line that shows the median value for each bar (cell) across all the `[Inst]`. (In the end I will add a band that displays 25th - 75th percentile but I figured working with the median would be simpler first).

I thought this would work, but it doesn't: `[AllInstMedian] = {fixed [Inst],[Dest Group], [Dest Cipn1] : Sum([N])} / {fixed [Inst] : Sum([N])}`

Any suggestions? I'm attaching a sample workbook [here](https://community.tableau.com/message/463964#463964) hoping that helps .

This is cross-posted [here](https://community.tableau.com/message/463964#463964)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve mayer commented on the tableau link posted in the question with an answer. I ended up using a `Lookup` trick to copy `inst` and then used table calculations on the `25th` and `75th` `window_percentile`.